# git - Copy History of A project with submodules to existing single project

Tags: git, migration, git-submodules, history

I have a git project contains 10 submodules project. I migrated this project to another as a single project. (All submodules are just a folder in the new project now)

Is there anyway to migrate the history data of files in the submodules to new one?

Comment: A Git submodule is a separate repository. You'll need to re-clone or migrate the ten *additional* repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each submodule, you would need to import their history into the main Git project repository.

You have an example in the 2013 article "[Integrating a submodule into the parent repository](https://x3ro.de/integrating-a-submodule-into-the-parent-repository/)" from [Lucas Jenß](https://github.com/x3ro).

The idea is to clone the submodule repository beside the main parent one:

```
•
├── parent/
└── sub/
```

[Remove the submodule declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309) in the parent repo:

```bash
git submodule deinit -f -- path/to/submodule
rm -rf .git/modules/path/to/submodule
git rm -f path/to/submodule
```

Rewrite the `sub/` repository history in order to move each element to the right path (the `path/to/submodule` one it was in the parent repository as a submodule)

However, Lucas is using a (now 2022) old obsolete `git filter-branch` command in order to move each submodule element to the path it needs to have in the parent repository:

```
CMD="git ls-files -s | sed \"s/${TAB}/${TAB}$TARGET_PATH\//\" | \
GIT_INDEX_FILE=\${GIT_INDEX_FILE}.new \
git update-index --index-info && mv \${GIT_INDEX_FILE}.new \${GIT_INDEX_FILE}"
```

It was valid (but cumbersome and not fool-proofed against corner case, like empty commits) in 2013.
These days (2022), it is achieved with [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/75e67bcd44014502cafff67cc8a93d2914f50510/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#moving-the-whole-tree-into-a-subdirectory=) (after [installation](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md), as it is python-based)

```
cd sub
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter path/to/submodule
# done!
```

Finally, merge the `sub` history into the parent one:

```bash
$ git remote add sub ../sub/
$ git fetch sub
$ git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit sub/master
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
```

Repeat that for all 10 submodules.
And you get one single Git project, with each submodule history preserved.

Comment: `-s ours` forces git to ignore the contents of the to be merged branch - only its history will be merged (unlike the `-X ours` variant of `-s recursive`). This is most certainly not what you want. Simply remove that part to merge the contents too.

Comment: @stefanct I agree, thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.