# Merging git submodule inside main repository with LFS objects

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, version-control, git-lfs

I am looking in how can I merge existing submodule to my main repository. Basically currently my repository looks somehing like this

```
├── example1.java
├── example2.java
├── img
|   └── image.jpg
└── submodule
    ├── sub_example1.java
    ├── sub_example2.java
    └── img
        └── sub_image.jpg
```

And submodule repository itself looks like this

```
├── sub_example1.java
├── sub_example2.java
└── img
    └── sub_image.jpg
```

What I am trying to achieve is add this `submodule` folder inside may main project.

`.gitattributes` on both repositories looks the same

```
*.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.odt filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.xls filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.xlsx filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.xla filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

so images from img folders are stored as LFS objects

I have tried to follow some tutorials, for example this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/72557462/8189102 where I would clone main repo and submodule repo beside each other like so

```
├── main/
└── submodule/
```

then I would checkout -b a local branch where I want to make changes

```
$ git checkout -b submodule-merge
$ git submodule deinit -f -- submodule
Cleared directory 'submodule'
error: could not lock config file .git/modules/submodule/config: No such file or directory
warning: Could not unset core.worktree setting in submodule 'submodule'

$ rm -rf .git/modules/submodule
$ git rm -f submodule
rm 'submodule'
```

Then on the `submodule` repository I would

```
$ cd submodule
$ git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter submodule
Parsed 501 commits
New history written in 2.12 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
Updating files: 100% (39508/39508), done.
HEAD is now at fa01cf43 Merge branch 'JRA-2221' into 'master'
Enumerating objects: 44721, done.
Counting objects: 100% (44721/44721), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (27931/27931), done.
Writing objects: 100% (44721/44721), done.
Total 44721 (delta 13961), reused 44721 (delta 13961), pack-reused 0
Completely finished after 7.69 seconds.

$ ls -l
submodule

$ git lfs ls-files
119926153d - submodule/img/sub_image.jpg
```

And then when trying to do the final merge

```
$ cd main
$ git remote add submodule ../submodule/
$ git fetch submodule
remote: Enumerating objects: 44702, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (44702/44702), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (27928/27928), done.
remote: Total 44702 (delta 13950), reused 44700 (delta 13949), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (44702/44702), 19.83 MiB | 14.37 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (13950/13950), done.
From ../submodule
 * [new branch]            JRA-117 -> submodule/JRA-117
 * [new branch]            JRA-221 -> submodule/JRA-221
 * [new branch]            JRA-333 -> submodule/JRA-333
 * [new tag]               b-211      -> b-211
 * [new tag]               b-333        -> b-333

$ git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit submodule/master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
  .gitmodules submodule

$ git status
On branch submodule-merge
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   .gitmodules
    deleted:    submodule

$ git commit -m "Rremoved submodule"
[submodule-merge 1683ee7b89] Rremoved submodule
 Committer: user
 2 files changed, 4 deletions(-)
 delete mode 160000 submodule

$ git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit submodule/master
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
```

`$ git status` also shows now all the new files added under `submodule` folder. Then I commit all the changes

```
$ git commit -m "Added submodule"
[submodule-merge 332f599182] Added submodule
 Committer: user

$ git status
On branch submodule-merge
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Next I try to push the changes to new branch and I get the following error regarding LFS object

```
$ git push origin submodule-merge
Locking support detected on remote "origin". Consider enabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://gitlab.example.com/main/main.git/info/lfs.locksverify true
Unable to find source for object 65cbf95fd1c7984cc8aca10ef81901e59e5bd42e05d177d1f7b6c95237a20b49 (try running git lfs fetch --all)
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/96), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
error: failed to push some refs to 'gitlab.example.com:main/main.git'
```

And I get stuck here with no idea what to do.
Also when running `$ git lfs ls-files | grep 65cbf95f` on both repositories (main and submodule) There are no results, its like this object has reference somewhere but actually it does not exist.

I would be very thankful if someone could help me to solve this.
Thank you!

Comment: See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049684/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories-with-lfs-objects#comment134124476_76049684) to a similar question. I believe the only way to do what you want is to remove LFS from the submodule, merge and then migrate the merged repository to LFS.

Comment: @phd Ok I tried to run `$ git lfs migrate export --include="*" --everything` first on submodule repo and also `git filter-repo --path .gitattributes --invert-paths --force` to remove .gitattributes file, and then adding this remote to main repo, and after running `git merge` I get `Encountered 1 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't: submodule/img/sub_image.jpg` But I was able to push it to my branch, but now this image file does not show up as LFS pointer. How can I now migrate it to LFS? I would like not to git lfs fetch --all, because the actual repo is like 25GB.

Comment: Could anything from https://stackoverflow.com/q/46704572/7976758 help?

Comment: Looks like running `git add --renormalize .` after `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit submodule/master` did actually help and I was able to push to main repository which uploaded submodule/img/sub_image.jpg as LFS object. Thank you @phd